# Javascript,How to roundup the values in string with £ symbol on final output

Tags: javascript

I need a help on roundup the values from the variable.

For this i am using the below JavaScript methods

- parseFloat()
- .toFixed(1)

**For example:**

I am getting values for percentage and numbers

```
var numericValue = "890.0789";// number
numericValue = parseFloat(numericValue).toFixed(1); 
console.log(numericValue);
// out put as 890.1

var percentageValue = "98.757%";//Percentage
if (percentageValue.indexOf("%") < 0){
   percentageValue = parseFloat(percentageValue);   
   percentageValue = percentageValue.toFixed(1); 
}
console.log(percentageValue);
//out put as 98.757%
```

for the Euro values output is **NaN**

```
var euroValue = "£16642.7890";// Euro

euroValue = parseFloat(euroValue);  
euroValue = euroValue.toFixed(1);
console.log(euroValue);
//euroValue is generating output as Nan

**Final out put, i am looking for "£16642.7"**
```

How to fix this.

Any help is appericiated.

**JSFIDDlE LINK**

http://jsfiddle.net/zv86xoxy/1/

Comment: `euroValue = '£' + parseFloat(euroValue.match(/([\d.]+)/)[1]).toFixed(1);` Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zv86xoxy/2/)

Comment: Thanks @Tushar, can you make this as answer, so that i can accept this.

Comment: Note: This is not the euro symbol, it's the british pound.

Comment: var euroValue = "16642.7890";
  euroValue ='£'+ parseFloat(euroValue).toFixed(1);

Comment: @Gerald Schneider, sorry i confused on the symbol. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the string contains alphabet characters, you need to remove them before using any math functions.

As the position of the `£` and `%` is fixed, `substr` can also be used.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/k8xpgtyy/1/)

```
percentageValue = parseFloat(percentageValue.substr(0, percentageValue.length - 1)).toFixed(1) + '%';

euroValue = euroValue[0] + parseFloat(euroValue.substr(1)).toFixed(1);
```

---

Regex can also be used to extract the Numbers.

```
euroValue = '£' + parseFloat(euroValue.match(/([-\d.]+)/)[1]).toFixed(1);
```

The regex `([\d.]+)` will extract the Number from the string and then euro symbol can be concatenated to the Number after using `toFixed` on it.

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/k8xpgtyy/)

```js
var numericValue = "890.0789"; // number
var euroValue = "£16642.7890"; // Euro
var percentageValue = "98.757%"; //Percentage

numericValue = parseFloat(numericValue).toFixed(1);
console.log(numericValue);

percentageValue = parseFloat(percentageValue.match(/([-\d.]+)/)[1]).toFixed(1) + '%';

console.log(percentageValue);

//euroValue is generating output as Nan
euroValue = '£' + parseFloat(euroValue.match(/([-\d.]+)/)[1]).toFixed(1);
console.log(euroValue);
```

---

Comment: @Tushar, one more help, how about '95.657%', can i get the output as 95.6%, in a single line of code with euro. you can see my above code, i am checking if condition with '(percentageValue.indexOf("%") < 0)';

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa Yes, check update and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/k8xpgtyy/1/)

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

H have removed `£` for variable,
this line,

```
var euroValue = "16642.7890";// Euro
```

If value is coming from `json`, try extracting the digits using `replace()`

```
euroValue = "£" + parseFloat(euroValue.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, "")).toFixed(1);
```

See [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zv86xoxy/8/)

Comment: the values are coming from the Json, so i believe we can not remove it.